# Inconsistent Resharper Installation Path

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

The installation path for Resharper appears different across several different computers we tried. In one, the default location was

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\Installations

while on other computers it was

> C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Locals\Installations

This usually would not be a problem, but however, since we're using dotCover from a batch file we're referencing the dotCover.exe directly, and the part *my_username* changes with different systems.

Also note that we're only using Resharper Ultimate 2016. I want to confirm if this is intended or not. It is possible it could be problems due to our system, but so far no other program have given varying install paths.

Comment: Thanks for that path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The installation path of R# depends on which installation mode has been used - per-user (LocalAppData) or [per-machine](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545259-How-do-I-install-ReSharper-for-All-Users-on-current-PC-) (Program Files (x86)). By default, ReSharper installer executes per-user installation, but if one selects Options | All Users checkbox, ReSharper installer will run the per-machine installation. So, it seems as if someone, who installed ReSharper on the first machine, used per-machine installation.